# Environment variables not found during Mocha unit test Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js

I am trying to run a mocha unit test but one of the modules used by the module I am testing on requires environment variables such as process.env.CLIENT_ID through dotenv. When I run my Mocha test, these environment variables are not found. How can I can include environment variables from a .env file in my mocha unit tests?

test.js:

```
    var messenger = require(__dirname + "/../routes/messenger.js");
var assert = require("assert") 


describe("Return Hello", function(){
    it('Should return hello',function(done){
        messenger.testFunction(function(value){
            assert(value === "Hello", 'Should return Hello')
            done()
        })
    })
})
```

Section of file that contains the problem that goes through unit test:

```
    var express = require("express")
var router = express.Router();

require('dotenv').config()

var plaid = require('plaid');
var mysql = require('mysql');

var fs = require("fs");


const plaidClient = new plaid.Client(
    process.env.PLAID_CLIENT_ID, // these are all not found
    process.env.PLAID_SECRET,
    process.env.PLAID_PUBLIC_KEY,
    plaid.environments.sandbox);
```

Answer (score 23, accepted):

to me the most elegant way of setting your env before the tests is **inside package.json**.

Here is an example to adapt to your own npm test command:

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "mocha -r dotenv/config"
}
```

The main idea is to add the **-r dotenv/config**.

The method works as well with **dotenv-flow**, do not forget to add **NODE_ENV=test** at the beginning of the command.

It works as well with **nodemon**.

Comment: if you need to pass a custom path for your .env file you can use `DOTENV_CONFIG_PATH` env variable

Comment: Note that this answer _sidesteps_ the problem instead of solving it. Passing the correct path argument to `dotenv` is the actually correct solution.

Answer (score 6):

I found the solution. I had to link the dotenv config explicitly to the location to the .env file by adding the `path:` options of the `.config()` method.

Example:

```
        var envPath = __dirname + "/../.env"
    require('dotenv').config({path:envPath})

// ^ this was incorrect

    var express = require("express")
    var router = express.Router();

    var plaid = require('plaid');
    var mysql = require('mysql');

    var fs = require("fs");


    const plaidClient = new plaid.Client(
        process.env.PLAID_CLIENT_ID,
        process.env.PLAID_SECRET,
        process.env.PLAID_PUBLIC_KEY,
        plaid.environments.sandbox);
```

Answer (score 0):

The below thing worked for me ;)

```
"scripts": {
        "test": "set DOTENV_CONFIG_PATH=test.env && mocha -r dotenv/config ",
      }
```

Comment: This may not work on windows and probably would throw an error like `'DOTENV_CONFIG_PATH' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.`

Comment: use `set DOTENV_CONFIG_PATH=test.env` or `export DOTENV_CONFIG_PATH=test.env`. depends on your OS and shell.

Comment: Never use `set`, use `cross-env`. Because you care about platform cross compatibility.